# Why does pytorch give an error related to matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pytorch

I have the following class for a neural network:

```
class NN_test(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden1 = nn.Linear(32, 32)
        self.act1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.hidden2 = nn.Linear(32, 8)
        self.act2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.output = nn.Linear(8, 1)
        self.act_output = nn.Sigmoid()
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.act1(self.hidden1(x))
        x = self.act2(self.hidden2(x))
        x = self.act_output(self.output(x))
        return x

model = NN_test()
model = model.to(torch.float64)
```

Also the optimizer and the loss counting function, as well as the learning cycle inside which I split the batch into 32 pieces and transfer them to the neural network.

```
# Create loss function
loss_fn = nn.L1Loss()

# Create optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params=model.parameters(), # optimize newly created model's parameters
                            lr=0.01)
torch.manual_seed(42)

BATCH_SIZE = 32

# Set the number of epochs 
epochs = 1000 
# Put data on the available device
# Without this, error will happen (not all model/data on device)
X_train = x_scaled.to(device)
X_test = x_scaled_test.to(device)
y_train = y_scaled.to(device)
y_test = y_scaled_test.to(device)



for epoch in range(epochs):
    for batch in range(0,len(X_train),BATCH_SIZE):
        ### Training
        model.train() # train mode is on by default after construction

        # 1. Forward pass
        y_pred = model(X_train[batch:batch+BATCH_SIZE])

        # 2. Calculate loss
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_train[batch:batch+BATCH_SIZE])

        # 3. Zero grad optimizer
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # 4. Loss backward
        loss.backward()

        # 5. Step the optimizer
        optimizer.step()

        ### Testing
        model.eval() # put the model in evaluation mode for testing (inference)
        # 1. Forward pass
        with torch.inference_mode():
            test_pred = model(X_test[batch:batch+BATCH_SIZE])
        
            # 2. Calculate the loss
            test_loss = loss_fn(test_pred, y_test[batch:batch+BATCH_SIZE])

        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print(f"Epoch: {epoch} | Train loss: {loss} | Test loss: {test_loss}")
```

This code gives the following error:
`RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x1 and 32x32)`

Yet i'm pretty sure that 32x1 matrix is multipliable by 32x32 matrix, so what's going on here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the full error traceback to the question. Currently, we don't even know where the error is occurring. Plus, assuming we have one matrix with shape `n x m` and another with `p x r`, they can only be multiplied if `m = p` (and the resulting shape will be `n x r`). Your shapes are incompatible.

Comment: Shouldn't the columns of the first multiplier be equal to the rows of the second to be multiplied? So in the example you've given it's n = r?

Comment: Matrix dimensions are given in row x column order. So yes, the columns of the first matrix (`m`) must match the rows of the second matrix (`p`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't enough information in the question to determine, but here is my best guess.

It looks like your input is a batch of items of shape `(32, 1)`, which is sent to a `(32, 32)` linear layer. You need the input size of the linear layer to match the number of features in the input, which in this case is `1`. Your layer should be `nn.Linear(1, 32)`.

The matmul happens between the last dimension of the input and the first dimension of the linear layer. The first dimension of the input is the batch size, which is irrelevant to the matmul operation.